# How to take a value from dropdown from Viewpage and pass it in the controller in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am creating a cascade dropdown with one being state and other being City .
When a user selects a State , I am storing that state id and then I want to populate City names corresponding to that State. I have used ViewBag to populate State and want to do the same for City but dont know how to pass State id from View page to Controller. 
My controller code :

```
public ActionResult ViewCitybyState(int? id)
        {
            List<string> a = null;

            if (id != null)
            {
                a = objmodel.ViewCitybyID(id).ToList();
            }
            ViewBag.Cities = a;
            return View(a);
        }
```

here id i want is of state id which I should get when a user selects a state which i know that we need to use onchange command

My viewPage

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.States,new SelectList(ViewBag.State,"Stateid", "States"),new {@id="ddlstates", @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value)" })
```

How to pass the value to controller ??

```
function CallChangefunc(val)
    {
       ?? // Not sure how and what to write here
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, If you are using ajax, You can do like that=>

```
function CallChangefunc(val)
    {
       $.ajax({
        url: http://localhost/Controller/ViewCitybyState,//Your route Here
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 
                id: val,                    
              },
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function () {                
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

---

Change controller action to:

`public JsonResult ViewCitybyState(string id)`

---

**Second**

---

In your view page, create the url to the server action and use `$.getJSON` like so:

```
// put your city dropdownlist into a variable
var cityDdl = $("#CityDropDownList");

// whatever variable you're storing the state value in
var stateIdValue = $("#StateDropDownList).val();

var submitUrl = '@Url.Action("ViewCitybyState", "ControllerName")';

$("#StateDropDownList").change(function() {
    $.getJSON(submitUrl,
        { id: stateIdValue },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            cityDdl.empty();
            cityDdl.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('-- Select City --'));
            if (response.length !== 0) {
                $.each(response,
                    function(index, item) {
                        cityDdl.append($("<option></option>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                    });
            }

        });
});
```

---

**Third**

---

Edit your controller action:

```
public ActionResult ViewCitybyState(string id)
{
    int ddValue;

    bool isNumber = int.TryParse(id, out ddValue);

    if(isNumber)
    {
        // _context is an assumption of what your connection string is
        // Cities is an assumption of the table you're using to hold the city names
        var cities = _context.Cities.Where(x => x.StateId == ddValue).Select(x => new { Text = x.CityName, Value = x.Id }).ToList();

        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!